# carouFredSel specific solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to keep opacity option when I switch the slider from manual-slider to automatic-slider?

Grid Carousel:

```
jQuery("#grid").carouFredSel({
    width: 5000,
    padding: 0,
    **auto: true,** - by defaulth it is set to false!
    prev: "#grid-prev",
    next: "#grid-next",
    items: {
        visible: 3,
        minimum: 1,
        start: -1
    },
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

Slider looks like this: [Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdLng.png)

As you can see in the picture, Active-panel is fully visible with full opacity, and the left and right one are faded with lowered opacity.
In code it is done like this:

```
// Highlight Center Panel
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var nextCenter = Math.ceil(jQuery(window).width() / 900);
    var prevCenter = Math.ceil((jQuery(window).width() - 900) / 900);
    jQuery(".grid-panel:eq("+prevCenter+")").addClass("active-panel");


    jQuery("#grid-next").click(function(){
        jQuery(".grid-panel").removeClass("active-pan+el");
        jQuery(".grid-panel:eq("+nextCenter+")").addClass("active-panel");
    });

    jQuery("#grid-prev").click(function(){
        jQuery(".grid-panel").removeClass("active-panel");
        jQuery(".grid-panel:eq("+prevCenter+")").addClass("active-panel");
    });
}).resize();
```

How to keep opacity option when I switch the slider from manual-slider to automatic-slider? (link and code above)

Comment: i am in heat.. hurry :)